# SLOW Java socket upload

Tags: java, sockets

We are trying to upload smallish files of 2-3MB over a socket connection with this code:

```
void startConnection(String ip, int port, int timeout) throws IOException {
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
    clientSocket = new Socket();
    clientSocket.connect(socketAddress);
    clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout((timeout * 1000));
    this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    this.output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), 
StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
this.output.flush();
}

recipient:
     projectx:
      server:
     ipaddress: xx.xx.xx.xx
     port: xxx
     username: xxxxxx
     password: xxxxxx
     timeout: 600
     poolsize: 5
     vaultkey: xxxxxxx



String sendRequest(String data) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    var myBytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myBytes);
   int read;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   log.info("starting transmission of {}", data);
   while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    log.info("sending packet {}", read);
    clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, read);
   }
   log.info("transmission ended");

  int count = 0;
  while (true) {
    log.info("hapana hapana");
    clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
    String receivedData = new String(buffer);
    count = (count + buffer.length);

  if (!receivedData.trim().isEmpty()) {
        response.append(receivedData.trim());
        if (response.toString().endsWith("|#|")) {
            break;
        }
    }
   }

  log.info("Read number of bytes: {}", count);

  return response.toString();
  }
```

Unfortunately it takes close to 5 minutes every time to upload via a good pipe.
I have seen in the forums that databuffer is better than datainput & output streams?
Not sure where the code goes south?

Comment: Don't torture your data, it will never confess. Replace the first 10 lines or so of `sendRequest()` with `clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` The loop after that is just wrong. If you knew to examine the return value of `read()` in the first loop then how could you not know to do so in the second loop?

Comment: The speed of sending may be limited by the receiving side. Do you control the receiving side too? How about the network between them, is it all on the same network or are there routers, switches, ..

Comment: We have a firewall to firewall connection setup with IP whitelisting. The pipe on both ends is substantial. I am more inclined towards a code deficiency.

Comment: Can you include the code for the receiving side in the question?

Comment: There is no  loop @PresidentJamesK.Polk until this problem manifested. The only reason I looped was to try and send the data in chunks and the response has been exactly the same. I also tried using BufferedWriter, it didn’t improve anything.

Comment: @Joni, the receiving end is pocessing as soon as they receive the file. It stays in "the dark" for 5 minutes while uploading from our end.

Comment: There must be something actively receiving the data and writing it somewhere, and acknowledging the data that has been received. Is the receiving side also written in Java or is it in another language? Do you have access to the code?

Comment: The receiving end is written in C# and their devs dont want to share this portion of code